# Trouble with SQL syntax when using JDBC and prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get this error message, when I try to execute an `UPDATE` query:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

And this is the code I have:

```
sql = "UPDATE object_1_ SET attr_2_ = ?";
prepared = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
prepared.setString(1, "abc");
prepared.executeUpdate();
```

However, if I slightly change the code and remove parameters:

```
sql = "UPDATE object_1_ SET attr_2_ = 'abc'";
prepared = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
prepared.executeUpdate();
```

then it works. So, I wonder what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You will have to supply the string value as `prepared.setString(1, "'abc'");` including the '.

Comment: Really??? I thought prepared statements exist to remove completely all those headaches with quoting, slashes etc. I think, you are not right. Besides in a real world I would have some variable like `prepared.setString(1, val);`. I checked this case and it also does not work

Comment: I checked it. Indeed single quotes did not help at all, as expected.

Comment: That code looks like it should work. What JDBC driver version are you using? You should use latest if possible, which currently is [5.1.37](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Comment: No, you don't have to add single quotes. But it don't see any erros ... sorry

Comment: @Andres. How can I check that? I installed it with `$ sudo apt-get install libmysql-java` and with `$ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar`

Comment: APT should be able to tell you. A jar file is a zip file, so you can view the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside the jar file. It usually includes the version number.

Comment: I checked `/usr/share/java/` folder and see that there is a jar file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.32.jar`

Comment: I also checked `MANIFEST.MF` and see there `5.1.32`. So, my version is relatively new.

Comment: Both code is working fine in MySQL. So, can you please share the complete code.

Comment: I think I provided everything I could.Besides, I should add, that I can prepare statements for `INSERT`ing and for `SELECT`ing. Only `UPDATE` does not work for some insane reason.

Comment: I have tried the same query in my database, and its working fine as expected.

Comment: Double-check your code to make sure that you are really doing `prepared.executeUpdate()`, not `prepared.executeUpdate(sql)`. It's a very common mistake.

Comment: Pheeeeew! Gord, your are right. I think different syntax for executeQuery and executeUpdate is really misleading.

Comment: The difference is not between `executeQuery` and `executeUpdate` *per se*, it's the difference between using a `Statement` (without parameters) and a `PreparedStatement` (with parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the code was actually doing

```java
prepared.executeUpdate(sql);
```

when it should have been doing

```java
prepared.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I wonder why this works - `http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/ `. I followed that example line by line and again got an error message. But when I switched to `preparedStatement.executeQuery()`, it started to work. Seems like this tutorial is misleading.

Comment: Yes, the first code sample on that page is wrong. Someone pointed that out in the comments 2 years ago, but it has never been fixed. (The "Full example" code further down on the page is correct.)

Comment: Even worse, with MySQL it only goes accidentally wrong (for example try a statement without parameters), while the JDBC specification demands that a `PreparedStatement` and `CallableStatement` always throws an `SQLException` when `executeXXXX(String)` methods are called.